# How to read, understand, analyze, and debug a Linux kernel panic?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, linux-kernel, panic

Consider the following Linux kernel dump stack trace; e.g., you can trigger a panic from the kernel source code by calling `panic("debugging a Linux kernel panic");`:

```
[<001360ac>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xf8) from [<00147b7c>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x50/0x60)
[<00147b7c>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x50/0x60) from [<00147c40>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x1c/0x24)
[<00147c40>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x1c/0x24) from [<0014de44>] (local_bh_enable_ip+0xa0/0xac)
[<0014de44>] (local_bh_enable_ip+0xa0/0xac) from [<0019594c>] (bdi_register+0xec/0x150)
```

- In `unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xf8` what does `+0x0/0xf8` stand for?
- How can I see the C code of `unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xf8`?
- How to interpret the panic's content?

Comment: Related: how to get the full trace: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208260/how-to-scroll-up-after-a-kernel-panic , question marks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113384/what-is-the-meaning-of-question-marks-in-linux-kernel-panic-call-traces

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's just an ordinary backtrace. Those functions are called in reverse order; the first function listed was called by the next. Below I added `[was called]` to further clarify:

```
(unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xf8) [was called] from (warn_slowpath_common+0x50/0x60)
(warn_slowpath_common+0x50/0x60) [was called] from (warn_slowpath_null+0x1c/0x24)
(warn_slowpath_null+0x1c/0x24) [was called] from (local_bh_enable_ip+0xa0/0xac)
(local_bh_enable_ip+0xa0/0xac) [was called] from (bdi_register+0xec/0x150)
```

The `bdi_register+0xec/0x150` is the symbol + the offset/length. There's more information about this in [Understanding a Kernel Oops](https://opensourceforu.com/2011/01/understanding-a-kernel-oops/) and how you can debug a kernel oops. Also, there's this excellent tutorial on [Debugging the Kernel](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/kerneldebug.html).

Note: as suggested below by Eugene, you may want to try [addr2line](http://linux.die.net/man/1/addr2line) first. It will need an image with debugging symbols though. For example:

`addr2line -e vmlinux_with_debug_info 0019594c(+offset)`

Comment: @0x90 I don't think you can't get the exact line *without* debugging the kernel, because that's an *instruction offset*, the best you could do with oops dump is to know the function that crashed.

Comment: Sometimes `addr2line` can resolve the address and determine the appropriate source lines. Of course, it is not always possible to map the instructions to the locations in the source code, but still, better than nothing. Debug symbols for the kernel are needed for that, of course. If one is lucky, they can be found either in `vmlinux` itself (for custom-built kernels) or in a separate package. Some distros provide such packages, the names may vary. `addr2line -e vmlinux_with_debug_info 0019594c` might help to find the source lines corresponding to `bdi_register+0xec`.

Comment: Perhaps this could be useful: I've recently experimented with `addr2line` and `eu-addr2line` (a similar tool from elfutils package) and found that the latter is more reliable. I used both to resolve an address in "e1000" driver with appropriate debug info. I copied the file with debug info (e1000.ko.debug in my case) to a different machine and tried to analyse it there with `addr2line -f -e e1000.ko.debug -j .devinit.text 0x424` and the same with `eu-addr2line`. Only the latter gave the correct results.

Comment: (contunued) When I did the analysis on the machine the driver was from, the results were the same as I described. `addr2line` pointed to a wrong location in the source code, `eu-addr2line` did things right. I cannot say now why it is this way, perhaps, something else is needed for `addr2line`.  In the meantime, I would recommend installing elfutils and using `eu-addr2line`.

Comment: @mux but how do you interpret a dot in the trace? I.e. in my case I saw the `(receive_room.isra.9+0x8/0x4c)`.

Comment: @Eugene: On my platform (Zynq board) `addr2line` works well with complete address (e.g., `addr2line -e vmlinux 4004578c`) and not with "symbol+offset" and `eu-addr2line` the reverse (e.g., `eu-addr2line -e vmlinux gwrr_balance.isra.20+0x11ac` gives the same as `addr2line` with complete address)

Comment: I suppose, link has been moved here: https://opensourceforu.com/2011/01/understanding-a-kernel-oops/

Comment: I was seeing `warn_slowpath_null` and `warn_slowpath_common` warnings from `sg_alloc_table`. can you help to understand under what scenarios these `slowpath` warnings will come.

Answer (score 24):

Here are two alternatives for `addr2line`. Assuming you have the proper target's toolchain, you can do one of the following:

**Use `objdump`:**

1. locate your `vmlinux` or the `.ko` file under the kernel root directory, then disassemble the object file :

   ```
   objdump -dS vmlinux > /tmp/kernel.s
   ```
2. Open the generated assembly file, `/tmp/kernel.s`. with a text editor such as `vim`. Go to
   `unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xf8`, i.e. search for the address of `unwind_backtrace` + the `offset`. Finally, you have located the problematic part in your source code.

**Use `gdb`:**

IMO, an even more elegant option is to use the one and only `gdb`. Assuming you have the suitable toolchain on your host machine:

1. Run `gdb <path-to-vmlinux>`.
2. Execute in gdb's prompt: `list *(unwind_backtrace+0x10)`.

---

*For additional information, you may checkout the following resources:*

1. [Kernel Debugging Tricks](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelDebuggingTricks).
2. [Debugging The Linux Kernel Using Gdb](http://elinux.org/Debugging_The_Linux_Kernel_Using_Gdb)

Comment: `gdb` did not work for me, although full debug symbols are included and I could debug remotely, in the past (I must have changed something...). `objdump` though, produced a very nice listing, including the source code, which was very precise and showed me the point causing the panic.

Comment: `gdb` is working fine with modules. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

> In `unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xf8` what the `+0x0/0xf8` stands for?

The first number (`+0x0`) is the **offset from the beginning of the function** (`unwind_backtrace` in this case).  The second number (`0xf8`) is the **total length of the function**.  Given these two pieces of information, if you already have a hunch about where the fault occurred this might be enough to confirm your suspicion (you can tell (roughly) how far along in the function you were).

To get the exact source line of the corresponding instruction (generally better than hunches), use `addr2line` or the other methods in other answers.