# kenrel Call trace func_name 0xde/0xad

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

In the kernel Call trace

```
[    1.356577] [c0000004f57131f0] [c0000000008fa9b4] .func_name+0xde/0xad
```

what does 0xde/0xad signify ? I guess the first one is instruction address - but what is the second one after /. How do i get to the exact instruction ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a linux kernel panic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468286/how-to-read-a-linux-kernel-panic)

Comment: Is is really `0xde/0xad`? Or should it be `0xad/0xde`? Offset should be less than size of the function.

Comment: As for "How do i get to the exact instruction" - do you want to find the instruction in the disassembly for the kernel or find the source code it corresponds to? It is not clear from the question.

Answer (score 2):

The format is as follows: `function+offset/length_of_function`. 'offset' is the offset of the instruction in the function, the number after the slash - length of the function, in bytes.

The answers to the question @nos mentioned ([How to read, understand, analyze and debug a Linux kernel panic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468286/how-to-read-a-linux-kernel-panic)) provide more detailed info here.