# What is the use of function size in linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

kernel oops shows info about RIP in the format of `function() + offset/size` but I have not found the 'size' info useful in debugging so far. As far as I know it is a static value defined by compiler/linker and has little to do with stack.

So in what situation would that be helpful or is it sort of redundant?

Comment: Have you seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468286/how-to-read-understand-analyze-and-debug-a-linux-kernel-panic)? The first is ***offset from the beginning of the function*** and the second is ***total length of the function***. Do you need the explanation how knowing the length of a function can be useful?

Comment: Thanks and yes I have checked that. Any idea what is the use of function length?  seems to me the offset + file symbol is good enough to root cause those issues.