# What does it mean if the top of a C++ call stack is "???" with all zeros as the address?

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm debugging from a crash log (C++, iOS), and I see a call stack that looks like this:

```
0 ??? 00000000 0 + 0
1 [ModuleName] 0x00130e3b MethodName
2 [ModuleName] 0x004ae417 OtherMethodName
...
```

Is the top of the call stack hinting at any obvious issue?  A null reference, perhaps?

Comment: You will also get that when no debugging information is available for a symbol.

Comment: Did the call stack come from a particular IDE or panic debugger? In general, it means the call stack may not be reliable and/or symbols were not loaded for that `dll` [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113384/the-meaning-of-in-linux-kernel-panic-call-trace)

Comment: Why is this question -3 with 2 close votes? Is debugging not programming-related, or is it illegitimate to ask how to read a call stack that has a "weird" entry that one doesn't understand?

Comment: It's a bit light.  Please provide the body of the funtion that it is supposedly in when this is the output.  could be a smashed stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that there is a null pointer on the stack where an address is expected. The null will be decoded to something chosen to draw your attention, not to something that provides any additional information.

So why is there a null on your call stack? Probably because of a stack overwrite in the function called from the previous method. Which of course is why you are debugging a crash dump.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a: "Oh, this is a telltale sign that X happened" if such an explanation existed.  This is the closest thing I've seen to that.