# Why linux stack addresses in call trace aren't sequential?

Tags: c, kernel

I have written a kernel module and tested it in qemu. In general, it's ok to run. However, after long-term execution, the kernel might abort. The printed call trace is very wired where the addresses of called functioned aren't sequential.`<ffffffffc0725fa5>, <ffffffffc0497e69>, <ffffffffc048953f>, <ffffffff9fc35cfc>, <ffffffffc0729f3e>, <ffffffffa01c539a>`In my opinion, the addresses should be ascending.

On the other hand, I can't understand the whole call trace. There is even an uncalled function in the call trace. The entry is `tamperhack_write` which then calls `kmem_cache_alloc_trace`(but why? It doesn't call this function). The abort appears in `kmem_cache_alloc_trace`. With so, why `tamperhack_write` can still go on and call the user-defined `tamper_is_safe_filename`?

[image]

Update:

The biggest confusion is why the kernel aborts on `kmem_cache_alloc_trace` which I have never explicitly called in user-defined functions `tamperhack_write` and `tamper_is_safe_filename`. However, there are `kmalloc` and `kfree` in my code.

Comment: Stack is sequential. The address of functions are push on stack at consecutive locations but the function address themselves do not have to follow any order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of question marks '?' in Linux kernel panic call traces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113384/what-is-the-meaning-of-question-marks-in-linux-kernel-panic-call-traces)

Comment: "On the other hand, I can't understand the whole call trace. There is even an uncalled function in the call trace. " - In a call trace records, marked with `?`, are **unreliable**. If omitting these records gives reasonable trace, then this trace is most likely the actual one.

Comment: @tstanisl Thanks for your response. You mean these addresses represent function addresses instead of stack frame entry addresses? It is totally contradictory to my knowledge. In my mind, the aforementioned addresses should be stack frame entry addresses. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes. Omitting those records with `?`, the whole trace seems more reasonable. However, the address of `system_call_fastpath`, which calls `tamper_write`, is still lower than `tamper_write`. This seems wired.

Comment: Addresses in the call trace represent addresses of the **"call" instructions**. These instructions are contained in the function's bodies, so the right side of the trace line represents the name of the function, where corresponding "call" instruction resides, and offset of that instruction in the function. Call trace doesn't contain addresses of the stack frames.